# Вывод содежимого таблицы из БД в таблицу Html

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь вывести данные из БД в таблицу html. Имеется таблица [image: data base]

Сам код вывода: `

```
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM goods');

    ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>category</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = $data -> fetch()) { ?>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($row as $col_value) { ?>
                    <td><?php echo $col_value ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

В результате значения почему-то выводятся 2 раза. [image: вывод]
Кроме того, поскольку с Pdo не очень хорошо знаком, покритикуйте.

Comment: Возможно потому, что по умолчанию  `fetch` извлекает в стиле `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` то есть возвращает массив, индексированный именами столбцов результирующего набора, а также их номерами (начиная с 0).... чтобы точно определиться и выводить только один, то надо писать либо `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` либо `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` либо еще какой  согласно докам:  http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод fetch() принимает не обязательный параметр, которым вы указываете в каком виде вы хотите получить данные, по дефолту этот параметр указывается как PDO::FETCH_BOTH который возвращает массив, индексированный именами столбцов результирующего набора, а также их номерами (значения дублируются)

Вместо

```
while ($row = $data -> fetch())
```

Напишите

```
while ($row = $data -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: Напиши еще почему, пжлст)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: я то знаю..). но ответ неплохо было бы дополнить почему - как для ТС, так и для тех, кто может столкнуться с такой же проблемой и искать решение и прийти сюда. А так - непонятно почему надо это сделать